# Service worker for web traffic analysis

Tags: service-worker

I have developed an application to analyse the network traffic while playing a youtube video. It uses **chrome.webRequest** and I calculate the traffic using **onHeadersReceived** event.

I want to do the same using **service workers** so that the application becomes browser independent. I fetch event of service worker, but it does not work.

Any suggestions how I can proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the broad idea is to listen to the fetch event, extract the information you need and allow the request to reach the network. You have a [working demo](https://serviceworke.rs/api-analytics/) in the Service Worker Cookbook: https://serviceworke.rs/api-analytics.html but the relevant code is here (in the cookbook you have the [annotated source](https://serviceworke.rs/api-analytics_service-worker_doc.html) as well):

```js
self.onfetch = function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    // Log the request…
    log(event.request)
    // …and then actually perform it.
    .then(fetch)
  );
};

// Post basic information of the request to a backend for historical purposes.
function log(request) {
  var returnRequest = function() {
    return request;
  };

  var data = {
    method: request.method,
    url: request.url
  };

  return fetch(LOG_ENDPOINT, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
  })
  .then(returnRequest, returnRequest);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Salva, but in my case http request is going through youtube iframe and fetch event is not recognizing it. I want to track the response data for the video. is it possible through service worker?

Comment: AFAIK, no, as the iframe is beyond the scope of the Service Worker. Maybe advances on [foreign-fetch](https://gist.github.com/mkruisselbrink/f6957bece64740926b84) in the specification will cover this use case.